# Set callback function of the PubSubClient API in class

Tags: c++, arduino, mqtt

I want to call the `setCallback()` function in a class constructor with a private method as parameter. That is not working because of the function signature required by the function. My problem with a function is that i am not able to access the private fields of a specific object  of my class.

I have already tried to create a simple function in the class file which did not work because of static context. I have also tried to just pass a method which is not working because of the signature.

```cpp
#include <PubSubClient.h>

class Test
{
private:
    void callback(char *topic, uint8_t *payload, unsigned int)
    {
        // things
    }

public:
    Test(PubSubClient psc)
    {
        psc.setCallback(callback);
    }
};
```

The following compiling error occurs.

```c
no suitable constructor exists to convert from "void (char *topic, uint8_t *payload, unsigned int)" to "std::function<void (char *, uint8_t *, unsigned int)>"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with arduino programming so my answer assumes you're referring to [this](https://github.com/knolleary/pubsubclient/blob/master/src/PubSubClient.h) class. Also, I don't know if your sample intentionally constructs using a value of PubSubClient? From what I can see it should be a reference or pointer e.g.

```
Test(PubSubClient& psc)
{
    psc.setCallback(callback);
}
```

The error message gives a pretty good explanation of what's wrong. The setCallback() method expects a std::function and it can't create one from the value of a class member function. The [example section of std::function cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function#Example) gives you a wide range of different ways you could make a std::function. If you're sure that your Test object will be alive for as long as the PubSubClient then I would suggest going with the std::bind example e.g.

```
Test(PubSubClient& psc)
{
    using std::placeholders::_1;
    using std::placeholders::_2;
    using std::placeholders::_3;
    psc.setCallback(std::bind( &Test::callback, this, _1,_2,_3));
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. Just to approve myself: the placeholders are just to hold place for the arguments(char *topic, uint8_t *payload, unsigned int) the callback **method** takes?